# Wildfly exploded war hot deployment

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss, wildfly

I have a web application deployed as exploded war using wildfly. What I want to get is

1. Changes in jsp files are automatically reflected, without redeploying the app
2. Changes in .class files enforce an app redeployment.

At the moment I am in a situation in which either I can get one option or the other, but not both at the same time (meaning that either every jsp change forces a new deployment or that .class files do not force a new deployment).

Current configuration of wildfly (using version 8.1.0) is

```
    <deployment-scanner 
            path="deployments" 
            relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" 
            scan-enabled="true"
            scan-interval="1000" 

            auto-deploy-exploded="true"
            runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}" 

            />

    ...

    <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config development="true"/> 
    </servlet-container>
```

Also, something I have found is that no matter what I set in the deployment-scanner config, once the server is up and running, if I go to the wildfly web console, the parameter auto-deploy-war is marked as true and auto-deploy-exploded is marked as false, even the scan-interval is always set to 5000 ms, which makes me think that the deployment scanner config is somehow being ignored.

I am kind of lost here quite frankly, it has to be possible for wildfly to reload the app if the change is a .class file and not do it if it is a jsp.

Comment: Yes, but first upgrade to 8.2 as 8.1 had broken jsp reloading

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/)? following my blog entries would help also.

http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/evaluating-jrebel-for-wildfly-and
http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/exploded-deployment-for-wildfly-on

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although JRebel or DCEVM could be options, I would like to start with the very basics.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse this configure would help: http://www.nailedtothex.org/articles-img/wildfly/servlet/behavior.png

Answer (score 0):

[Manik Hot deploy](https://manik.imixs.org/) is an open source Maven Plugin that simplifies your web development. The plugin provides both deployment modes - the auto-deployment and also the hot-deployment. It can be easily configured in a maven project by adding the plugin to the pom.xml

```xml
  ....
  <build>
    <plugins>
    .....
      <!-- Manik Hotdploy -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.imixs.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>manik-hotdeploy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <!-- List Source and Target folders for Autodeploy and Hotdeploy -->
          <autodeployments>
            <deployment>
              <!-- wildcard deployment -->
              <source>target/*.{war,ear,jar}</source>
              <target>/opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments/</target>
              <unpack>true</unpack>                     
            </deployment>
            </autodeployments>
            <hotdeployments>
              <deployment>
                <source>src/main/webapp</source>
                <target>/opt/wildfly/standalone//deployments/my-app.war</target>
              </deployment>                     
            </hotdeployments>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        .....
      </plugins>
    </build>
    ....
```